# Query whether Python's threading.Lock is locked or not

Tags: python, multithreading, thread-safety, locking

I have a thread I am running (code below) which launches a blocking subprocess. To ensure that other threads do not launch the same subprocess, I have a lock around this `subprocess.call` call. I also want to be able to terminate this subprocess call, so I have a stop function which I call from somewhere else. In the event that the subprocess is stopped prematurely, I want to release the lock as well, which is what the below code does:

```
class SomeThread(threading.Thread):
   def run(self):
      aLock.acquire()
      self.clip = subprocess.call([ 'mplayer', 'Avatar.h264'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
      aLock.release()
   def stop(self):
      if self.clip != None and self.clip.poll() == True:
         try:
            self.clip.send_signal(signal.SIGINT)
         except:
            pass
      aLock.release()
```

However, according to the documentation [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#lock-objects), calling `release()` on a released lock will raise an Exception:

```
A RuntimeError is raised if this method is called when the lock is unlocked.
```

Is there a query function like `aLock.isLocked()`?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Sure!

```
>>> from threading import Lock
>>> x = Lock()
>>> x.locked()
False
>>> x.acquire()
True
>>> x.locked()
True
```

You could also do a non-blocking acquire:

```
x.acquire(False)
x.release()
```

In this case, if `x` was unlocked then the code acquires it, and releases it.  But if x was already locked, the non-blocking acquire returns at once (and returns `False`), and we again release it.  But that's subject to races!  There's nothing to stop some other thread from releasing the lock *between* those two lines.

Ditto for checking `.locked()`.  That only tells you the state of the lock at the time `.locked()` was executed.  It may no longer be true by the time you execute the next statement.

By the way, the body of `run()` is better written using the lock as a "context manager", like so:

```
def run(self):
    with aLock:
        self.clip = subprocess.call([ 'mplayer', 'Avatar.h264'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
```

This does the `acquire()/release()` pair for you, and is much more robust against unexpected exceptions raised in the body of the `with` block (Python does all it can to release the lock if the body is exited for *any* reason).

Comment: It's like inception...we have to go deeper

Comment: Well why doesn't [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#lock-objects) mention the `locked()` function?

Comment: It does mention it in the docs, but it's easy to miss. It's at the bottom, in a different format than the rest of the functions: `locked()
Return true if the lock is acquired.`

Comment: @ChickenFeet `threading.lock` is different with `multiprocessing.lock`, in `multiprocessing.lock` we haven't `locked()`